# How to override block with plugin in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, plugin

I want to override a **_prepareLayout** function of the block **module-catalog-search/Block/Result.php** .

```
 protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $title = $this->getSearchQueryText();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($title);
        // add Home breadcrumb
        $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
        if ($breadcrumbs) {
            $breadcrumbs->addCrumb(
                'home',
                [
                    'label' => __('Home'),
                    'title' => __('Go to Home Page'),
                    'link' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
                ]
            )->addCrumb(
                'search',
                ['label' => $title, 'title' => $title]
            );
        }

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

In above function, if I want to change the breadcrumbs name from **Home > Search Result** to something else. 
How can I do it with the help of plugin ?

Comment: Dinesh Yadav, in default m2......  "`Search results`" coming . where`Search` comming?

Comment: I was just giving the example. If it's already "Search  results",  Can you please tell me how to change that text "search results" ? . I just want to change it with the help of plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earlier I didn't know that Plugin cannot override protected functions. A plugin can override only public functions. So it's not possible to override given method using a plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution is that use [translations](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html)

Translation is simple way with doing less code:

Create ***a translation file*** at ***theme translation folder***

> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[Theme]/i18n/[Your_Lanague_Code].csv

and write code

```
"Search results for: '%1'", "My results for: '%1'"
```

See how use  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by two ways:

1) using Preference

2) using Plugin

**Preference** is similar to class rewrite in Magento 1. There is always possibility of conflict when two or more custom modules try to rewrite/override same core class.

There is **Plugin** to address the limitation of **Preference**. With Plugin, we can execute our code before, after and around the core/target class’s function. We don’t replace the core/target class’s code/function. We just add some code before/after the core code. It’s somehow similar to event observer. We just observe the core/target class’s function and execute our code in-between the core/target class’s function. Multiple modules can use their own plugins to add their own code before/after/around the same core/target class’s function.

**Using Preference**

Here are the examples of rewriting Block, Model, Controller, and Helper class using Preference. I suppose the module name as YourCompany_YourModule.

We have to define preference in in app/code/YourCompany/YourModule/etc/di.xml. There we define the core/target class which we want to rewrite. We also define our module’s class that is going to rewrite the core/target class.

**BLOCK OVERRIDE**

**`app/code/YourCompany/YourModule/etc/di.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" type="YourCompany\YourModule\Block\Catalog\Product\View" />
</config>
```

Let’s rewrite getProduct() function of class Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View. We will just log some message on var/log/debug.log for this test.

**`app/code/YourCompany/YourModule/Block/Catalog/Product/View.php`**

```
<?php

namespace YourCompany\YourModule\Block\Catalog\Product;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{
    /**
     * Retrieve current product model
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        // logging to test override    
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug('Block Override Test');

        if (!$this->_coreRegistry->registry('product') && $this->getProductId()) {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($this->getProductId());
            $this->_coreRegistry->register('product', $product);
        }
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override block with Plugin, make sure the methods you want to use Plugin are not:

- Final methods
- Final classes
- Non-public methods
- Class methods (such as static methods)
- __construct and __destruct
- Virtual types
- Objects that are instantiated before Magento\Framework\Interception is bootstrapped
- Objects that implement Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\NoninterceptableInterface

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html